# converting binary number to decimal number in String

Tags: java, binary

I got a task where I need to write a code that converts a binary number to a decimal number in a `String`.
The main problem is that the binary bit length can be as long as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which means 2^31 times the number 1 in a line), and I can't use `BigInteger`.

I know the algorithm of converting binary number to decimal, I just don't get how to write the code that makes even "1111....111" (33-MAX times) into decimal.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Let's unpack your question, because there really are, two parts to it.

> binary bit length can be as long as INTEGER.MAX_VALUE (which means 2^31 times the number 1 in a line), and i can't use BigInteger.

For the aforesaid concern, my suggestion is you take a visit [here](https://cs.fit.edu/%7Eryan/java/language/java-data.html). Now, I've done even the Googling for you. Since you said you know the algorithm for conversion, why don't you go ahead and calculate the max possible value any string could take on when converted into a number, and try to find what numeric type in Java can accommodate that. This is of course under the assumption that you're allowed to return any numeric type decimal number.

On the note of algorithms, here's the second part to your question:

> I know the algorithm of converting binary number to decimal, i just don't get how to write the code that makes even "1111....111"(33-MAX times) into decimal.

And that's how we all started... not knowing how to write code! I suggest a `for` loop might come in handy to parse each character of the provided `string`, but that's the most hints I'll give you for now. Try to figure it out, write some code, and do some more searching on the internet if you want (although writing code is going to be faster of a process and stretches your brain muscles too!).

Still stuck? Come back, and we'll discuss. But, have some code to show for it!

Answer (score 0):

For big integer use `import java.math.BigInteger;`  library.
To conver in decimal use `decimal=Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2);`